# Javascript Array delete or pop causing race condition with console.log?

Tags: javascript

On the current Google Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.79, on an iMac with Mountain Lion), the following code

```
var arr = [1, 3, 5];
console.log(arr);

delete arr[1];
console.log(arr);

console.log(arr.pop());
console.log(arr);
```

will show

```
[1, undefined × 2] 
[1, undefined × 2] 
5 
[1, undefined × 1]
```

there are also other situation that caused Firefox to behave similarly as well.  Are they bugs on Chrome and Firefox -- but it would seem strange that both Firefox and Chrome are susceptible to similar bugs -- or is it some behavior with array delete and `console.log`?  Supposedly, `console.log` should not be running on a separate thread.

Comment: As a workaround print: `arr.toString()`

Comment: do you know why a workaround is preferred?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: @動靜能量: Seems like a bug that was done by the same person. FF14 is fine, while FF15 is not. Vandalized?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/5849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to queued up `console.log` processing, so the printing is delayed, and it shows a later version of the object or array: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

My answer there has 5 solutions and `JSON.stringify()` was the best one.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 7.0:

var arr = [1,3,5];

console.log(delete arr[1]); // *will show [1, undefined, 5]*

And in my opinion it's a correct behavior =) So may be it's just a bug.

Comment: The op is not asking why the result is `[1, undefined, 5]`.

Comment: a similar bug showed up on Firefox 15.0.1 but it involved 10 tests for `arr1` to `arr10`, and if I removed the test for `arr9`, then the output became "correct", and if I removed the test for `arr1` to `arr8`, the output became "correct" again.  `arr10` is totally independent of other array tests, so it is similar to what Chrome was showing in the original question

Comment: So `delete` is working correct and `console.log` isn't. If you do not re-define the `console.log`, I would suggest that this is simply a bug of browsers.